# Best and/or shortest way to do strict (non-type converting) <, >, <=, >= comparison in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, the `==` comparison has a strict (non-type converting) version: `===`. Likewise, `!=` has the strict form `!==`. These protect you from the following craziness:

```
var s1 = "1",
    i1 = 1,
    i2 = 2;

(s1 == i1)   // true, type conversion
(s1 != i1)   // false, type conversion

(s1 === i1)  // false, no type conversion
(s1 !== i1)  // true, no type conversion
```

However, the other comparison operators have no equivalent strict modes:

```
(s1 < i2)   // true, type conversion
(s1 <= i2)  // true, type conversion
([] < i2)   // true, wait ... wat!?
```

The obvious solution seems pretty verbose:

```
((typeof s1 === typeof i2) && (s1 < i2))  // false
```

Is there a more idiomatic (or just less verbose) way to do this in Javascript?

Reference: MDN [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: But don't those operators only make sense if both operands are of the same type? What would you expect for something like `[] < 1`, or `{} >= []`?

Comment: @bfavaretto But  `"2" >== 1` should return false

Comment: I think he is saying something more along the lines of `"1" < 2`. I use strict cases to prevent stupid logic errors in my code, and I assume that is what he is doing as well.

Comment: ((s1 === i2) && (s1 < i2)) is not working?

Comment: @thatidiotguy, exactly. I want versions of the operators that never return true for different types like the strict equals and not equals. Or Javascript should have never allowed type automatic type coercion for comparison operators but that's for a different argument.

Comment: Got it now. There are no built-in operators for that, but you can always create a function.

Comment: @Adam: but that will always be false. If s1 and i2 are both numbers then I want the test to pass if s1 is less than i2.

Comment: @kanaka No. If s1 and i2 are both numbers and s1 is less than i2 it returns true.

Comment: You might be able to build your own with a preprocessor/macros for JavaScript such as [`sweet.js`](http://sweetjs.org/)

Comment: @Adam, check your example again. Either `===` is true, or `<` is true, but never both.

Comment: @clentfort sweet.js looks really sweet

Comment: @JuanMendes I have not used it yet, I just spotted it on a news page a few days ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no built-in operators for what you want, but you can always create your own functions. For example, for `<`:

```
function lt(o1, o2) {
    return ((typeof o1 === typeof o2) && (o1 < o2));
}
lt("10", 11); // false
```

Another option, if you're only dealing with strings and numbers, is extending `String.prototype` and `Number.prototype`:

```
function lt(o) {
    return ((typeof this.valueOf() === typeof o) && (this < o));
}
String.prototype.lt = lt;
Number.prototype.lt = lt;
"10".lt(11);   // false
(11).lt("12"); // false
```

Comment: `new Number(11).lt("12")` can be shortened to `(11).lt("12")`

Comment: Thanks @Juan, changed the example to your version, looks much cleaner.

Comment: Is this the only way? Coming from different language background, this feels pretty weird.

Comment: @mjaything I'm guessing you're coming from a language that has either strict typing, or operator overloading — or both. JS has neither, so the solutions to this ends up being cumbersome. The JS way to handle that is [a type coercion algorithm](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison).

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a pretty clean and smart solution by using `.prototype`!

Answer (score 9):

How about creating a Object and using it

```
var strictComparison = {
    "<" : function(a,b) { return ((typeof a === typeof b) && (a < b)) },
    "<=" : function(a,b) { return ((typeof a === typeof b) && (a <= b)) },
    ">" : function(a,b) { return ((typeof a === typeof b) && (a > b)) },
    ">=" : function(a,b) { return ((typeof a === typeof b) && (a >= b)) }
};

console.log(strictComparison["<"](5,"6")) ;  
console.log(strictComparison[">"](5,6)) ;
```