# (greater than and lower than) or equal strict forms

Tags: javascript

greater than or equal than `>=` and lower than or equal than `<=` strict versions in JavaScript? Similar to `===` and `!==`.

example:

```
false >= 0
true
false >== 0
VM174:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =(…)
```

For "Y you will ever need it?"

```
!undefined >= 0 // some bad code like this in 10000 rows for example
true
```

example of defined strict versions, greater or equal than strict and respectively the other way around can be defined too.

```
function gtEStrict(arg1,arg2){
  if ( typeof arg1 === typeof arg2 ) {
     if ( arg1 >= arg2 ) {
       return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}

gtEStrict(0,0)
true
gtEStrict(!undefined,0)
false
```

Comment: only numbers can be compared this way so why do you need the non-existent strict equal?

Comment: No, these operators don't exist. And why would you need them anyway?

Comment: Are you trying to do that because `false` evaluates to `0` and `true` evaluates to `1`?

Comment: There's no feasible reason or way to determine if a value AND type is gt/lt another data type. You can compare the *string*'d types and it will compare ascii values (unicode?) but that's irrelevant

Comment: no, but `<` and `>` only work on numbers and strings, so there's not as much ambiguity as there is with general equality comparison.

Comment: @Jon addition to my post

Comment: @vtz, there is no silver bullet for "some bad code"

Comment: @vtz, btw, please tell me languages having gte/lte-strict comparsions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, no.  These operators do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's assume, that comparing operator `a >== b` exist. When it return `false`, what does it mean? `a` less than `b` or `a` does not strictly equals to `b`? You can read more in [that anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14533299/238336).

Comment: i will mark this an answer because of the link :) (good one). Obviously there is no standard operator for my question i was curious if someone faced this and waned to make quick dirty fix or checker ;)

Comment: ah this will be confusing for beginners :) replacing with +1 and changing my answer to @molsons's