# how js compares a str with a number

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

when I receive user's age, but I don't change it to number, I can understand if my client's age is 18 or not...

```js
var isAge = prompt("How old are you?");
alert(typeof isAge) //string
if (isAge >= 18) {
  alert("you can enter the site")
} else
  alert("you cant enter the site")
//it knows if the str in below 18 or not
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Not convert the input to string and then verify if the input given is a number that's above or below 18?

Comment: Do you need to use `parseInt()`?

Comment: Maybe reading about type coercion will help you here.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion

Comment: There's general reasoning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533046/why-doesnt-javascript-have-strict-greater-less-than-comparison-operators). But the short answer is that's just how JS works.