# Perils of <= and >= in Javascript. How to avoid them?

Tags: javascript, operators, type-conversion

Bill the Lizard stated the dangers and cons of using the equality operator (`==`) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/870776). However, little has been said about the undercover "evil twins", the `>=` and the `<=`.

```
0 >= ''      // true
0 <= ''      // true
'' >= 0      // true    
'' <= 0      // true
```

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Should elements of different types be comparable by default?
   1.1 If not, what should be the returned value? `false`? `undefined`? Bear in mind that if `a >= b === false`, this implies that `a < b === true`.
2. What could be done to avoid, **in a practical way**, odd cases as the ones in the example?
3. Since greater than (`<`) and less than (`>`) operators also do type conversion, are there any odd cases for them?

Comment: Just the perils of javascript, I guess.  [WAT](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091058/best-and-or-shortest-way-to-do-strict-non-type-converting-compari) may be of interest.

Comment: Great questions.  I would, by convention, do type conversion in such cases, as 0 < '' doesn't make sense, while 0 == '' kind of does.  Also, FWIW, === isn't bullet-proof, either.  +0 === -0, per http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.6

Comment: Or you make sure the data you are comparing is what you are dealing with and these issues do not matter.

Comment: (To my previous comment, avoiding misleading wording.  IEEE754 says -0 === +0, so ECMA is proper, but my point was: if you care about zero sign, you need to handle it accordingly -- just as you would in eg C.)

Comment: You would have a proper partial order, if you used `function less (a,b) { return typeof a <= typeof b && a <= b; }`. `less(0, '') == true`. `less('', 0) == false`.

Comment: '' becomes 0 in type conversion so all examples are moot.

Comment: a >= b false implies nothing. Think a = NaN or undefined, for instance.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I meant from a logical/mathematical point of view; `x >= 3 => 3 < x`

Comment: @eversor No, `x >= 3` implies `3 <= x`.

Answer (score 3):

> Should elements of different types be comparable by default?

This only matters if you are designing a language. In JavaScript, values of different types are comparable, and comparison follows certain rules. You have to be aware of them, but I don't see any point in discussing "what if the rules were different".

> What could be done to avoid, in a practical way, odd cases as the ones
>   in the example?

Just avoid comparing values of different types, it doesn't make sense if most cases. The only situation where it's useful is comparing numeric strings with numbers. And in that case JavaScript behaves just as anyone would expect, no odd results.

> Since greater than (<) and less than (>) operators
>   also do type conversion, are there any odd cases for them?

I'm sure there are, although I can't think of one right now. But why you think your examples are odd? You seem to understand that `"" == 0` because of type conversion, so it's no wonder all the comparisons in your example return `true`, as they all include zero.